# Adding a href tag to a long string from a JSON

Tags: android, json, regex, href, replaceall

I've been stuck on a problem where I have a json object with a value in it titled **message**, which will have lots of string and some will even contain links in the format below (like how this site has different formats for their bold, italics, etc)

> [[www.randomwebsite.com]] gives www.randomwebsite.com

or

> [[www.randomwebsite.com random]] gives random

The regex that I have for the top one is:

```
\[\[.[^\]]*\]\]
```

and I'm doing a `.replaceAll` to try and add the href tags to it, but it isn't working as I feel I've done it wrong. My code for that is

```
String htmlHyperlinkMessage = htmlStrikeMessage.replaceAll(Constants.HYPERLINK_REGEX, "$1<a href=\"$2\"></a>");
```

but this gives me an array out of bounds exception and I'm just stuck on this, can anyone give any suggestions?

It's greatly appreciated, I have looked around on the forum but I couldn't find anything related to my example as the format for different hyperlinks has confused me.

**EDIT**

Here's my stacktrace logcat

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:579)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendEvaluated(Matcher.java:138)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:111)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:319)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:1600)
at com.myapp.android.model.PostItem.getMessage(PostItem.java:98)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat stacktrace

Comment: The regex doesn't look right to me. For example, you didn't escape the square brackets.

Comment: What is that $1 at the beginning of your href String?

Comment: @abbath I was following the standards of the java regex I found on this for bold and italic and put that there too thinking it's be the same...but I'm sure it isn't

Comment: @IlyaKogan the regex pattern is taken from the iOS app that uses the same kind of thing and I had trouble converting the functionality from swift to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're replacing something with a group (like `$1`, `$2`), you need to capture that group using parentheses. You're getting an out-of-bounds exception because `$1` tries to find a group you made, but your regex `\[\[.[^\]]*\]\]` contains no groups.

If you want to capture the contents of [[]] as a group, you can add parentheses: `\[\[(.[^\]]*)\]\]`

For a further explanation, read the "**3.4. Grouping and back reference**" part of this article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

And the replacement `"$1<a href=\"$2\"></a>"` doesn't seem right either. It should be something like `"<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>"`

By the way, I don't think the `.` character in your regex is needed. It does make sure the square brackets aren't empty, but you can achieve the same effect more clearly by replacing the `*` with `+` like this:

`\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]`